# What is meant by a "fast outfield"?

Tags: cricket, terminology

They always say in commentary that the outfield is very fast? what does it exactly mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that the ball, when hit along the ground, will travel quickly. The "speed" of an outfield can be affected by two major factors:

- **Length of the grass** - if the outfield has been cut short, there will be less friction on the ball as it travels over it, and hence the ball will decelerate at a slow rate.
- **Moisture** - a damp outfield will cling to the ball, slowing it down.

Comment: I think the OP asked about the meaning of the word `outfield`. We can hear on the commentary "quick outfield" when the batsman hits the ball hard.

Answer (score 2):

The outfield is a sporting term used in cricket and baseball to refer to the area of the field of play further from the batsman or batter than the infield, and in association football to players outside the goal.

> They always say in commentary that the outfield is very fast? what it is exactly mean?

The Quick/Fast Outfield refers to the outfield which has a less friction offered when ball travels on the ground.

In simple words the [Outfield](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outfield) where the ball travels much faster than the regular outfields can be called quick/fast outfield.This may be because of the grass height/a dry outfield as suggested by Spinner in his answer or it may be even because of the slope of the ground which affects in acceleration of the ball.

As quoted by many commentators/batsmen/captains the quick outfield helps the batting side to score more amount of runs.

Answer (score 1):

The term *Fast Outfield* means where grass or friction is less and the ball travels quickly to the boundary after hitting.

Answer (score -1):

outfield means the area in between square(means set of pitches) and the boundary line.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to Sports.SE. The question is "what is meant by a *fast outfield*?" and not "what is *outfield*?".